# How to set parameter in crystal report in asp .net?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Refer to the post

http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-string-parameter.htm

asp .net will automatically have a textbox or datetimepicker to input

However, after input and refresh report, the textbox and submit button disappear

1. How to show the textbox and button again?
2. And the function in the post not work after passing datetime value toshortdatestring() from calendar control

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameter to crystal reports manually. By this way, you can create your own parameter's form and you can handle the user input to send it to the report. Here is a snippet to show you how you can do that:

```
ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
doc.Load(Path.Combine(basePath, report.Name + ".rpt"));
doc.SetDataSource(dataTable);

// set parameters defined in Paramenter fields inside the rpt
var value = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
value.Value = valueYouWantToPass;
doc.ParameterFields["nameOfTheParamenterField"].CurrentValues.Add(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
        Imports CrystalDecisions
        Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports
        Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
        Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

        Dim RptDoc As New ReportDocument()
        Dim CrTables As Tables
        Dim CrTable As Table
        Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
        RptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(ReportFullFilename))

                    With crConnectionInfo
                        .ServerName = "myServer"
                        .DatabaseName = "myDatabase"
                        .UserID = "myUserID"
                        .Password = "myPassword"
                    End WITH

        CrTables = RptDoc.Database.Tables

        For Each CrTable In CrTables
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
        Next

        RptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(crConnectionInfo.UserID, crConnectionInfo.Password, crConnectionInfo.ServerName, crConnectionInfo.ServerName)


        RptDoc.SetParameterValue("FromDate", FromDatePicker.SelectedDate)
        RptDoc.SetParameterValue("ThruDate", ToDatePicker.SelectedDate)

        Dim stream As New BinaryReader(RptDoc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.[Shared].ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat))
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & downloadAsFilename)
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.BaseStream.Length.ToString())
        Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.BaseStream.Length)))
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()
```